# Does this fall under "exact duplicate"?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590156/after-sorting-an-array-while-setting-a-variable-the-original-array-gets-sorted) that is really similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952598/why-is-sorting-modifing-the-original-in-this-case) (answered by the same user), but I'm not sure if it's close enough to be a duplicate.

I would delete it, but the answer is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: I voted to close as dup.

Comment: @nhahtdh And your motivation for that is? It might help this question along.

Comment: @Bart: I looked too quick through the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has an answer, and is asking for the question that it answers, and the other is asking a question which is answered.  No, they are not exact duplicates (The questions, in isolation, are different), but since both have been answered the entire Q/A of each has all of the same information.

The fact that a single answer could answer two questions doesn't make those questions duplicates.

Comment: You got a point there.

Comment: *Thousands* of questions would have to be closed as duplicate, if that were the case. =)